# System of linear equations, 2 solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm thinking about an easy proof, why an System of linear equations can't have 2 solutions. I know that it can only have 0, 1 or infinitely many. But why are only these possibilities possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the linear system $Ax = b$ has at least two solutions $x = x_1$ and $x = x_2$.

Then, for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, we have  $A[tx_1 + (1-t)x_2] = tAx_1+(1-t)Ax_2 = tb + (1-t)b = b$.

Thus, $x = tx_1 + (1-t)x_2$ is also a solution for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

So, if a linear system has more than 1 solution, then it has infinitely many.